# Create x509 Certificate issued by CA from command Prompt

Tags: openssl, makecert

I want to generate a X509 cert which should be issued by Root Certificate Authority from command prompt. I tried tools like makecert, selfssl7 but all they are doing is generating a self signed cert. How can we generate a cert that is issued by root CA? This is for testing purpose only. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  You generate a [CSR](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Certificate_signing_request).  The CSR is given to the CA, and the CA gives you the certificate in return.  The [bible](http://www.opensslbook.com/) describes how to generate a CSR, and how to take the CSR and root key and turn it into an x509.  I think it's in chapter 5.